Android Native Firebase notification sound issue after Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1
After Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1, custom sound for the notifications stop working. Receives the notifications with the default device notification sound.
Code implementation
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(FROM_PUSH, 1);

    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                (this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
    } else {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    Uri defaultSoundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
            "://" + getPackageName() +
            "/" + R.raw.noti6);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.get(TITLE))) {
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(data.get(TITLE));

    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.get(TEXT))) {
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(data.get(TEXT));
    }
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    notificationBuilder.setColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notif);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
        channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.canShowBadge();
        channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setSound(defaultSoundUri, audioAttributes);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt((10000 - 1222) + 1) + 1222, notificationBuilder.build());

}
Current issue- Receives notifications with the default device notification sound.
Desired Result- Receive notifications with the custom notification sound.

THis has nothing to do with FCM.  FCM doesn't show notifications and the system neither knows nor cares that you're showing one in response to an FCM messge.  This is just a problem with the notification itself.
The main problem is likely due to this, from the documentation on setSound:

Note: An app-specific sound can be provided in the Uri parameter, but because channels are persistent for the duration of the app install, and are backed up and restored, the Uri should be stable. For this reason it is not recommended to use a ContentResolver#SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE uri, as resource ids can change on app upgrade.

I'd put the file into assets instead of resources, or possibly even move it to the filesystem.  Really it's not a good idea to load anything that doesn't have to be into resources, as resources are loaded at launch and if you're not constantly using it you're just wasting memory and time loading it.
